# Column headers from different dataset in MS Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, dynamic-columns

I basically need to load table headers from one dataset and table data from another. Is it possible to do with MS Reporting services?

As I can see table is associated with the data by DataSetName property and it can be only one dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can include data from a different dataset to the one linked to the table by including the dataset name in the expression, for example:

```
=First(Fields!HeaderField1.Value, "HeaderDataset")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. I actually used Matrix control instead of a table.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset isn't dynamic, then you can manually define the dataset (or edit it) Ctrl + alt + D (I think) should pop the dataset window open (in RS2005/2000) failing that I think it's under: view - other windows

I have used this where a stored proc uses temp tables and RS is unable to determine the final dataset structure correctly.